# Am I using namespaces wrong?

Tags: design, c++, organization, namespace

I'm obsessed with organization - it's probably the real reason why I enjoy coding. So I namespace everything. But I'm just curious if I'm doing it wrong by being redundant.

Consider this, which I think is correct

```
namespace System {
   class File {};
   class Monitor {};
   class Logger {};
}
```

Now consider this, which is what I seem to be doing

```
namespace System {
   class SystemFile {};
   class SystemMonitor {};
   class SystemLogger {};
}
```

Am I being redundant? It's just that, `SystemFile` is a file in the system. `SystemMonitor` monitors the system.

In use cases, which would you prefer?

```
class Application {
   public:
      System::Monitor monitor;
      // or
      System::SystemMonitor monitor;
};
```

Comment: It all depends on whether you suspect users will be declaring `using` statements.  If someone declares `using System;` then you don't need the `System::` prefix for any class declared inside of it.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch We never use `using` thankfully

Comment: And this is all internal code?  Sounds like `System::Monitor` would be preferred in that case.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch May be the other way round. If everything is called SystemThis, SystemThat then there is much more temptation to use "using System;".

Comment: This is called 'Smurf-naming', and a lot of people frown about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The problems with Avoiding Smurf Naming classes with namespaces](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191929/the-problems-with-avoiding-smurf-naming-classes-with-namespaces)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Am I using namespaces wrong?

*Wrongly*. It's an adverb.

And the answer is *probably*.

> In use cases, which would you prefer?

There are several reasonable tests. Is one easier to read, easier to say, easier to type, easier to fit in a readable expression or otherwise easier to use?

Can you take something out without impairing clarity, legibility, usability or correctness?

```
System::SystemMonitor monitor;
```

So, in my head this sounds like "system system monitor monitor".

Why not `System::SystemMonitor systemMonitor`? Or `System::SystemMonitor::Monitor systemMonitor`? Because they add more typing with no extra information and *no benefit*.

Conversely, if we start from `System::SystemMonitor` and *simplify* to get `System::Monitor` - can you see any downside? I can't, and if you can simplify something while keeping it clear and correct, you should generally do it IMO.

---

There are a couple of valid reasons to prefix types with the module name. One is that you're writing C, and the other is that you expect people to inject the whole namespace with `using`. You already ruled both of those out, so you have no excuses left for making your type names worse.

Comment: I agree. Now what about a case such as, `Xml::File` which extends `System::File`. Users within the `Xml` namespace will simply be able to create `new File()`, but will it be hard to understand that this is not a simple old `File`, rather it is an `XmlFile`? Because then you're back to `Xml::XmlFile` ...  these are the things that keep me up at night.

Comment: I disagree. "Wrong and wrongly are both adverbs, meaning incorrectly, badly, or mistakenly.. Usage authorities differ on whether using wrong this way is acceptable, but in real-world usage, the adverbial wrong is not just widely accepted but common". "Am I using workspace wrong" is perfectly fine.

Comment: @errno_44, as you already rule out injection of names with `using`, any name that you see without a namespace prefix must either come from the current namespace or the global namespace. I would expect a half-decent programmer to be able to easily remember or determine what namespace they are currently working in and the global namespace is likely to be nearly empty if you extensively use namespaces. That makes is rater easy to determine that `new File()` will create an `Xml::File` object if you are working within the Xml namespace.

Comment: @gnasher729 - I'm not usually a prescriptivist, but I felt it helped to establish the right level of pedantry for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of course of your intent.

If you intend to avoid naming conflicts and use primarily qualified names, the lean approach would be less redundant and easier to read: `System::File` is more convenient than `System::SystemFile`

If on the other side you prefer to inject full namespaces  with `using`, then of course `SystemFile` would be less ambiguous. But what sense does it makes to create very specific namespaces in the first place, if it is for dissolving them in some kind of global magma afterwards.

Then, comes the question of consistency. Suppose that  after a while, you decide to nest your `System` in a `Platform` namespace.  With the lean approach you need not no worry: it’ll be `Platform::System::File`.  With the redundant approach, you’ll need to decide if tou keep `SystemFile`, or if you go for `Platform::System::PlatformSystemFile`. So your names start to be coupled to the namespace organisation. This goes against the principle of separation of concerns.

Then come more advanced namespace strategies. Suppose that in reality you have a `MacOS` namespace and a a `WindowsOS` namespace, each implementing a slightly different `File`. At compile time you do some configuration, using [namespace alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias). For example:

```
 namespace System = Platform::MacOs;
 ....
 void doSomething() {
      using System::File;    // works regardless of alias choice
       File xxx; 
        ...
  }
```

So, separation of concerns, i.e. keeping “item” names independent of the enclosing namespace offers you much more flexibility.